# How to access HttpContext.Current.User custom attributes in the view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to access some custom attributes in my view from a `User` object. I am implementing custom attributes for authentication and I am changing the `HttpContext.Current.User` inside of my global.asax.

This is the `User` class

```
public class User : IPrincipal
{
    ...
    public bool IsAdministrator => IsInRole(RolesConstants.GlobalAdministrator);
    ...
}
```

Here is where I am setting it in my `Global.asax`

```
    protected void WindowsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate(object sender, WindowsAuthenticationEventArgs e)
    {
        ...

        var winUser = new User
        {
            EMail = user.Person.Email,
            FirstName = user.Person.FirstName,
            LastName = user.Person.LastName,
            Identity = wi,
            NetworkAccountName = user.UserName,
            UserId = user.UserName,
            Roles = userRoles,
        };

        HttpContext.Current.User = winUser;
    }
```

As an example how can I do something like this?

```
<button type="button" visible="@User.IsAdministrator" id="btn"></button>
```

Since the `User` object is already accessible I don't want to pass in a `Model` or use a string in the view such as `@User.IsInRole("Admin")`

Edit: should I be making a custom type derive from `IPrinciple` and explose the types like this?

```
...
        IIdentity Identity { get; }
        bool IsInRole(string role);
        bool IsAdministrator;
...
```

Comment: Are you sure that @User is available in the view?

Comment: You can create a custom `RazorViewBase` class and derive your views from it. The custom class can provide your own implementation of User to views.

Comment: @Kevin, yes it is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to cast the `User` property to your custom class:

```
@{
    var user = User as MyNamespace.User; // MyNamespace is the namespace of your User class
}

<button type="button" visible="@user.IsAdministrator" id="btn"></button>
```

*[Edit]*

Another quick-and-dirty solution using an extension method:

```
public static class ViewUserExtensions {

    public static User ToCustom(this IPrincipal principal)
    {
        return principal as User;
    }
}

<button type="button" visible="@User.ToCustom().IsAdministrator" id="btn"></button>
```

Comment: The extension method is only accessible on the server side. Is there something missing to implement it? I would rather have that than a variable for the view

Comment: Of course it is, as the view is rendered server-side. Remember to add the correct using statement inside your view so you can use the extension method `@using MyNamespace`, where `MyNamespace` is the namespace containing the `ViewUserExtensions` class.

Comment: Doh, Thank you very much!